# Types in multi document f# solution. How to work with them?

Tags: types, f#

I am quite new to FSharp and I am currently trying to call from my main method some custom types I created.

I created the types in the same namespace as the main method of my application..so I believe that they should be within range to be invoked but they aren't... what should I do?

This is my code :

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.net
// See the 'F# Tutorial' project for more help.

namespace ProductUrlUpdaterFSharp

open System
open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
open System.Data.SqlClient

#light
namespace MyApp
module Main =
    open System
        [<EntryPoint>]
        let main args =
                    let endofapp = Console.ReadKey();
                    // Call 'GetProducts' procedure with 'CategoryID' set to 1
                    use conn = new DynamicSqlConnection(connectionString)

                    0
```

And this is my type in another .fs document :

```
namespace ProductUrlUpdaterFSharp


open System.Data
open System.Data.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders  
open System
open System.Data.SqlClient
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Wrappers with dynamic operators for creating SQL Store Procedure calls

type DynamicSqlDataReader(reader:SqlDataReader) =
  member private x.Reader = reader
  member x.Read() = reader.Read()
  static member (?) (dr:DynamicSqlDataReader, name:string) : 'R = 
    unbox (dr.Reader.[name])
  interface IDisposable with
    member x.Dispose() = reader.Dispose()
```

Comment: The problem is likely that F# requires you to sort the dependencies manually - so your helper types need to be *before* your main file.